# Get CPU Usage in Mac ObjC Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cpu-usage

Can anyone help me out on getting just the system cpu usage value for use in a gui application.

Thanks

Comment: I guess this might be a very correct solution for your problem: [get-cpu-usage-from-application][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223348/ios-get-cpu-usage-from-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to use the host_processor_info call, but unfortunately there's little to no documentation out there. (Unfortunately, there's no nice Cocoa library for such things.)

As such, you might want to take a look at the source code for [CPU Usage](http://boredzo.org/cpuusage/) by Peter Hosey and see how he's solved the problem.