# How to get the Memory usage & CPU usage of particular iOS App?

Tags: ios, memory, cpu

I am having trouble in getting memory usage of a particular iOS application . Also i want to make sure that what ever output result i am getting is for particular running app on iPhone.

Comment: Since we can't read your mind, explain what you are actually trying to achieve. There's a button in Xcode to achieve what you want - if I'm guessing right.

Comment: I want to get it done programatically or Terminal !

Comment: when you run your app on simulator, you can check it on debug Navigator pane, you can open debug navigator pane by "Command + 6". or you can Go to Product --> Profile. after attaching your device, there you can use different instruments to check memory leak, performance etc. also you can record a session.

you can visit this link for more detail, http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode

Comment: @parth I want to code the same .

Comment: **What** do you want to get done "programatically or Terminal"? Try to improve your communication skills. I still haven't learned how to read your mind.

Comment: @gnasher I have stated it clearcut that when an app is running on my iPhone i want to know that what amount of memory it uses in iPhone . I do think I have stated it clearcut .

Comment: Is there any other clarification required & btw where does communication skills come into picture ?

Answer (score 3):

Please check the answer on this thread,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/787535/4030948

here is the way to get used memory bytes for your app.

And for the CPU usage of your application,
please check the answer on this thread,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8382889/4030948

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is to select the 6th icon along, on the left panel in XCode.

Make sure you have selected to run your project on the iphone device you are looking for, and keep an eye on these usage monitors as you use the app.  A more thorough analysis is available using Instruments, but this is the quickest way.

Comment: I want to get it done programatically or using terminal .

Comment: That's why posting a badly thought through question, making someone waste their time, is extremely impolite.

Comment: @gnasher if you know the answer then you are welcome.. Else I am not here to waste my time like you . Rather I would have answered if I were you..  Before correcting someone try to answer the question... Coz this portal is ment for it... If you know it then ans it...