# High CPU usage - what is it?

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

Can't find out the problem that cause a high CPU usage (150% - 180%) in my app at a certain point.

The UI works pretty well anyway.. but there's something in background that cause that without even touching the UI.

[image]

[image]

I'm new to Instruments.

Happy to provide some additional code if needed!
[iOS 9.1.2 - Xcode 7.2]

Comment: Try to check the `Hide System Libraries` button, then you can see the method name you write.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223348/ios-get-cpu-usage-from-application/8382889#8382889